# Get another chunk of data

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I would like to load another chunk of the list when button Load More is clicked. On this stage a chunk of loading list replacing the existing one. Here is the codepen link `http://codepen.io/shaolin_monk/pen/PNWoQG?editors=1000`.
Regarding API:

- Get chunk of pokemon list `http://pokeapi.co/api/v1/pokemon/?limit=12`
- Get information about single pokemon
  `http://pokeapi.co/api/v1/pokemon/{{id}}`
- Image of pokemon `http://pokeapi.co/media/img/{{id}}.png`
- All possible types `http://pokeapi.co/api/v1/type/?limit=999`

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For further reference, please make a fiddle here instead of another website so that the info will be always available in the future. Well, it is replacing the data because that´s what you are telling it to do:

```
  $http.get('http://pokeapi.co/' + url).success(function(data){
      $scope.pokemons = data
  });
```

Instead of replacing (=), you want to just add the new pokemons. If you check data, it is an object with meta information and an objects array. So you need to replace the meta information (tells where we are), but add the new pokemons to the objects array. This fixes it:

```
  $http.get('http://pokeapi.co/' + url).success(function(data){
      $scope.pokemons.meta = data.meta
      $scope.pokemons.objects = $scope.pokemons.objects.concat(data.objects)
  });
```

Here is the working fiddle:

```js
var pokedexApp = angular.module('pokedexApp',[]);

pokedexApp.controller('pokedexCtrl', ['$scope', '$http',
    function ($scope, $http){
        $http.get('http://pokeapi.co/api/v1/pokemon/?limit=12').success(function(data){
            $scope.pokemons = data;
        });

    $scope.getInfo = function(id){
      $http.get('http://pokeapi.co/api/v1/pokemon/' + id).success(function(data){
          $scope.pokemonInfo = data;
      });
      $('#pokemon-details').css('display', 'inline-block')
      $('#pokemonPic').attr('src', 'http://pokeapi.co/media/img/'+ id +'.png')
    };

    $scope.loadMore = function(url){
      $http.get('http://pokeapi.co/' + url).success(function(data){
          $scope.pokemons.meta = data.meta
          $scope.pokemons.objects = $scope.pokemons.objects.concat(data.objects)
          
      });
    }
   }]);
```

```css
#pokemon-list{
  display : inline-block;
}
#pokemons{
  width : 500px;
  display : inline-block;
}
  li {
    border : 1px solid black;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 10px 5px 0 ;
    list-style: none;
  }
  span {
    display: block;
  }
  button {
    display: block;
  }
  #pokemon-details{
    display : none;
    vertical-align: top;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app='pokedexApp'>
    <div ng-controller='pokedexCtrl'>

      <div id='pokemon-list'>
        <ul id='pokemons'>
          <li ng-repeat='pokemon in pokemons.objects' class='pokemon'>
            <a href="#" ng-click = "getInfo(pokemon.pkdx_id)">
              <h3>{{pokemon.name}}</h3>
              <img ng-src="http://pokeapi.co/media/img/{{pokemon.pkdx_id}}.png" width='100' alt="{{pokemon.name}}" />
              <span ng-repeat='type in pokemon.types'>{{type.name}}</span>
            </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <button type="button" ng-click='loadMore(pokemons.meta.next)'>Load More</button>
      </div>


      <div id='pokemon-details'>
          <img src="" id='pokemonPic' width='200'/>
          <h2>{{pokemonInfo.name}} #{{("0000" + pokemonInfo.pkdx_id).slice(-4)}}</h2>
          <table border="1">
            <tr>
              <td>Type</td>
              <td><span ng-repeat='type in pokemonInfo.types'>{{type.name}} </span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Attack</td> <td>{{pokemonInfo.attack}}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Defense</td> <td>{{pokemonInfo.defense}}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>HP</td> <td>{{pokemonInfo.hp}}</td>
            </tr>objects.
            <tr>
              <td>SP Atack</td> <td>{{pokemonInfo.sp_atk}}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>SP Deffense</td> <td>{{pokemonInfo.sp_def}}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Speed</td><td>{{pokemonInfo.speed}}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Weight</td><td>{{pokemonInfo.weight}}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Total movesS</td><td>{{pokemonInfo.moves.length}}</td>
            </tr>
          </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: @DeniChan no problem, feel free to accept answer if it has fully resolved your issues. Was interesting to find out about that api as well :)